# Unfortunately application has stopped in Android because of EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a little problem with checking length of EditText.

```
text = take.getText().toString(); 
if (text.matches("")) {
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter first  value", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

take is a EditText and text is a String.

When i run my app without Edittext value i got an Error:
 Unfortunately "ApplicationName" has stopped.

In my Class i have

```
private EditText take;
private String text;
```

Please help me, i try to use method `.equals("")` or `.length()==0` but stil the same.

Comment: What does your logcat say? Where are you getting your EditText?

Comment: have you assigned the edit Text to your View ?

Comment: Yes i assigned it
I will show you logcat little later because now i am outside the home

Answer (score 1):

you may have forgotten findViewById or you are calling it before setContentView of your activity!

Answer (score 0):

Some time match and equal will not return proper. I prefer to use a function to check empty value.

```
public static String chechNullState(EditText checkTextBox) {
        String makeModVal = null;
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty( checkTextBox.getText().toString() ))
        {
            makeModVal=checkTextBox.getText().toString();
            return makeModVal;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
item =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.take);
String takeVal = chechNullState(item);
if ( !takeVal == null)
{
  //do what ever you want;
}
```

Comment: Can you post log cat view as others asked ?